# Range selector with Highchart Dumbell Chart

Tags: highcharts

I am creating a  chart using Highchart Dumbell chart and want to display a range selector within it.
So is there any way that we can create range selector with Dumbell chart like snap  :  [Dumbell Chart image][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHDC4.png

Answer (score 0):

To use navigator with `dumbbell` series in the required way, you would have to add some custom code to modify the navigator (to be able to use it on y-axis) or create a separate chart only with navigator and connect it with the base chart - please see the example below.

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bmnv369z/

---

Another way is to use basic line series with modified data:

```
var lineSeries = data.map((el, i) => ({
    data: [
        [el. low, i],
        [el.high, i]
    ]
}));

Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    ...,
    series: lineSeries
});
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gfabem8o/